# Laravel 9 - GET http://localhost:8000/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I can't use the app.css in my application
I use
  `<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: did you try compiling your assets? npm run dev or npm run watch

Comment: @vite("resources/css/app.css")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the asset() helper starts with the `/public` folder. If you have already taken this into consideration then the only problem will be that you have not run `npm run dev`.

```
public/
    |--- css/app.css
    |---js/
```

`<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` = `public/css/app.css`

Answer (score 0):

Check your asset url in .env file. If it is missing add it in your .env file

ASSET_URL=public

and run php artisan config:cache.

Answer (score -1):

if

```
public/
    |--- css/app.css
    |---js/
```

and

```
<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> = public/css/app.css
```

not work you can use

```
<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

or you can use

```
<link href="{{asset('asset/css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```